# dataTables search number from formatted number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, datatables

I'm using the dataTables to search data in my HTML table.

A problem occurs when I try to filter by number. The numbers are formatted so they aren't being filtered as they should.

An example:

In the table, I have a cell that contains "123,456" (instead of "123456").

If I type in the search box "1234" it will filter out the number. If i type "3,456" it will find what I'm looking for.

I've tried formatting the numbers typed in, but that doesn't work good enough (it will format '1234' to '1,234', so it won't find '123,456' because the comma is misplaced. Another example - if I'll look for '50', it would filter out 5,000):

```
$( "#activity_table_filter input" ).keydown( function(){
        var current_value = $( "#activity_table_filter input" ).val();
        current_value = current_value.replace(/,/g, ''); //remove any commas from current value.
        var key = event.keyCode;
        var entered_value = String.fromCharCode( (96 <= key && key <= 105) ? key - 48 : key ); //charCode doesnt really get numpad numbers

        if( !isNaN( current_value ) && current_value != '' && !isNaN( entered_value ) ){ //if current and entered value are numeric, and current value is not an empty string
            if( current_value % 1 === 0 && current_value.length >= 3 ){ //if the number is an integer and has 3 digits
                current_value = current_value + '0'; //add a last char
                var formatted_value = parseInt(current_value).toLocaleString(); //format to beautiful
                formatted_value = formatted_value.toString(); //Convert to string
                formatted_value = formatted_value.slice(0,-1); //remove added '0' from the end
                $( "#activity_table_filter input" ).val( formatted_value ); //change value of input to formatted input.
            }else{ //if the number is a float

            }
        }
});
```

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Added, but i can't really see how it could help. If you'll look for 50, it woudln't find 5,000 that's written somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to this problem but I will mention two the most simple.

1. For HTML-sourced data, use cell `data-search` attribute to specify non-formatted number.

   For example:

   ```
   <td data-search="123456">123,456</td>
   ```

   See [HTML5 `data-*` attributes - cell data](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) example for demonstration and more information.
2. For JavaScript and Ajax-sourced data, you can use do the same with [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option.

   jQuery DataTables uses term [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) meaning that it may use different data for different purposes.

   Your data then need to include two additional properties, `display` for displaying in the table and `search` for searching.

   ```
   {
       "data": [
           {
               "formatted_number": {
                   "display": "123,456",
                   "filter": "123456"
               },
               "office":     "Edinburgh"
           }
       ]    
   }
   ```

   To use the data in this format, use the following options for a `columns` or `columnDefs` column description:

   ```
   {
       data: 'formatted_number',
       render: {
           _: 'display',
           filter: 'filter'
       }
   }
   ```

   See [Orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data.html) example for demonstration and more information.

Comment: All you needed to do is post the  HTML5 data-* attributes - cell data link. That works perfectly. Thank you. It acctually even solved me another problem which i didn't write here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the developmental [search plugin](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search#Inputs)? It's much better at searching integer data than the `smart search` option. See the example using a range of integers from the [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) below. Just make sure your integer data is [rendered](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) as such in the table. There are also [custom renderers](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers) that will help you format those integers with commas.

```
/* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
        var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
        var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

        if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
             ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
} );
```